# Relaunch a GWT-RPC request after a failure

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I'm using RpcRequestBuilder to intercept and do some general modifications to every RPC I make on my application.
Is there a way, to if I caught a throwable on my RpcRequestBuilder, and I know that I should try to do the RPC again, relaunch the same RPC? It's theoretically possible, I just don't know what to same to launch the RPC request again. 
(and yes, I will be careful not to enter on a loop :) )

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply calling `send()` on the `RequestBuilder`?

AFAICT, the only issue would be if you have an async method with a `Request` (or `RequestBuilder`) return type: the returned `Request` will be the one from the first request, the second request will be ignored, and thus couldn't be aborted by the calling core.
To allow for that case, you'd have to return a subclass of `RequestBuilder` from your `RpcRequestBuilder`'s `create()` method, overriding `send()` to return a special `Request` subclass that delegates to the *real* `Request` (and allowing it to be *swapped*, so you could set the one corresponding to the retry).

Comment: I actually don't have such an async servicce, but since the first rpc failed (executed onFailure(Throwable) on the AsyncCallback), that really shouldn't be a problem right? As the second request, would trigger onSuccess with the expected result.

I can give you an example:
Lets say I use some kind of session management and that i verify the validity of the session on every rpc. Now, if the session is detected as a "timed out", one would show a login box, and after a successful login, i want to repeat the first rpc, the one that originated the timeout/login screen.
Is this doable using send() ?